# Passing PowerShell data variables to Terraform scripts

Tags: powershell, terraform

I have a PowerShell script:

```
#collecting  user input for  client_id,  client_secret, subscription_id, and tenant_id
$client_id = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your Azure client_id'
$client_secret = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your Azure client_secret'
$subscription_id = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your Azure subscription_id'
$tenant_id = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your Azure tenant_id'

# Read the JSON payload from stdin
$jsonpayload = [Console]::In.ReadLine()

# Convert JSON to a string
$json = ConvertFrom-Json $jsonpayload
$client_id = $json.client
$client_secret = $json.secret
$subscription_id = $json.subscription
$tenant_id = $json.tenant
```

I want to pass the variables `$client_id`, `$client_secret`, `$subscription_id`. Using data "external".

How can I pass these data to Terraform?

Comment: Hello! Is it about Terraform from https://www.terraform.io/? If so I would suggest to add this link to the word "Terraform". What do you mean with "using data external"?

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes Terraform from from Terraform.io . Terraform.io provides a provider called  "data external" for passing data from python, powershell. I do not know how to pass data from powershell scripts to Terraform. Had done my research and writing the codes but my code is having errors.
 
 Thanks for helping.